# Unknown salesforce error

Tags: trigger, schedulebatch, gack

I received the following error message when a batch apex job is being executed:

> Salesforce System Error: 2034297691-23646 (-1315618792) (-1315618792)

I have also checked the logs and this is what appears before the transaction ends

```
09:39:20.334 (4279944450)|DML_BEGIN|[735]|Op:Insert|Type:B4F__Event__c|Rows:48
09:39:21.356 (4356997609)|DML_END|[735]
09:39:21.356 (4358093205)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false
09:39:21.356 (4358230816)|FATAL_ERROR|Internal Salesforce.com Error
```

I have checked, and there is no trigger for that object, and I have also tried commenting the insert line, printing the list as a string to try to insert it after the transaction ends, and I got no error message. The weirdest part is that this was working perfectly fine for weeks, but suddenly, it is failing, any ideas?

Comment: Did you check the API usage? Might be an issue there. If it worked before were there any changes to the job? Any changes to infrastructure?

Comment: Based on our Salesforce backend logs I see the message as "SQL Exception for entity CustomEntityDataTemplate. This Gack is unlikely to be caused by Apex, but happened in an asynchronous apex process." for the GACK Id -1315618792. Please consider logging a case with salesforce support for further investigation.

Comment: I will do, many thanks!